# How to merge Multi Index in pandas with different index levels?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two pandas DataFrames :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['0','0','1','1','2','3','3'],
                  'friend_id':['1','2','3','2','4','4','5'],
                 'date_sent':['01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-02-2020'],
                 'date_accepted':['01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-02-2020',None,'01-10-2020',None,'01-21-2020']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['1','1','2','2','3','3'],
                  'page_liked':['A','B','A','C','B','D']})

grouped1 = df1.groupby(['user_id','friend_id']).count()
grouped2 = df2.groupby(['user_id','page_liked']).count()
print(grouped1)

output >>>

                  date_sent  date_accepted
user_id friend_id 

0       1                  1              1
        2                  1              1
1       2                  1              0
        3                  1              1
2       4                  1              1
3       4                  1              0
        5                  1              1

grouped2

output >>>
user_id page_liked
1   A
    B
2   A
    C
3   B
    D
```

I am trying to merge `grouped1.friend_id` with `grouped2.user_id`. The goal would be to obtain the following table:

```
user_id friend_id       page_liked

0       1                  A
                           B          
        2                  A      
                           C    
1       2                  A
                           C         
        3                  B
                           D         
2       4                  Na          
3       4                  Na              
        5                  Na
```

I've tried doing `merge` in multiple ways with no luck since the indices are multi level. I have also tried `grouped1.combine_first(grouped2)` but this seems to only work when the index levels are the same, so I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: What is grouped2?

Comment: When I print grouped2 does not give me what you have in the output

Comment: @DaniMesejo just try typing `grouped2` into your IDE. For some reason when you do `print(grouped2)` it does not print anything, and that is most likely because the data frame is only an index.

Comment: grouped2 = df2.groupby(['user_id','page_liked']).count() , updated in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments in answers for key steps using reset_index(), renaming the column and doing another groupby.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['0','0','1','1','2','3','3'],
                  'friend_id':['1','2','3','2','4','4','5'],
                 'date_sent':['01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-02-2020'],
                 'date_accepted':['01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-02-2020',None,'01-10-2020',None,'01-21-2020']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['1','1','2','2','3','3'],
                  'page_liked':['A','B','A','C','B','D']})
#Use reset_index() to change indexes to columns and for group 2 rename the column to match the column you want to merge with
grouped1 = df1.groupby(['user_id','friend_id']).count().reset_index()
grouped2 = df2.groupby(['user_id','page_liked']).count().reset_index().rename(columns={'user_id':'friend_id'})
#merge and drop unnecessary columns and then do another groupby if you want to re-index.
grouped3=pd.merge(grouped1, grouped2, how='left', on=['friend_id']).drop(['date_sent', 'date_accepted'], axis=1)['page_liked'].min())
grouped3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`. It supports multiindex dataframe merging on multiindex.

You need to change index level name of `grouped2` to match index level name of `grouped1`. Since you want to match on a single index level, just change the name of one level. So, on `grouped2`, change level name `user_id` to `friend_id`. Finally, join, reordering index levels, and reset_index and slice

```
df_out = grouped1.join(grouped2.rename_axis(['friend_id', 'page_liked']), 
                       how='left').swaplevel(0,1).reset_index(level=-1)[['page_liked']]

Out[82]:
                  page_liked
user_id friend_id
0       1                  A
        1                  B
        2                  A
        2                  C
1       2                  A
        2                  C
        3                  B
        3                  D
2       4                NaN
3       4                NaN
        5                NaN
```